# Combining two functions in Scheme

Tags: function, recursion, scheme, lisp, composition

I have the filter-function and the reverse-function done out in my own code

```
(define reverse_
  (lambda (xs)
    (if (null? xs)
        xs
        (append (reverse_ (cdr xs))
                (list (car xs))))))
```

and

```
(define filter_
  (lambda (p? xs)
    (if (null? xs)
        xs
        (append (if (p? (car xs))
                    (list (car xs))
                    (list))
                (filter_ p? (cdr xs))))))
```

I want to combine the two functions into the `(reverse-filter)` function i.e you could type `(reverse-filter symbol? '(1 2 3 a b c))` and it would return `-> c b a`.

It works now by simply typing `(reverse_ (filter_ symbol? '(1 2 3 a b c))) -> c b a` but I just want to combine the two.

Any help on doing this in the general case and in this specific one would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case, we can use the [`curry`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29) and [`compose`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._compose%29%29) procedures (which hopefully are available in your interpreter), they allow us to manipulate other procedures:

```
((compose (curry filter_ symbol?) reverse_)
 '(1 2 3 a b c))
=> '(c b a)
```

For illustrative purposes, here's a naive implementation of both procedures, to understand what they're doing under the hood:

```
(define (curry f x)
  (lambda (y) (f x y)))

(define (compose f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`compose` is the right and lazy thing to do, however since lists are iterated from head to tail but created from tail to head creating the reverse result is actually more efficient when done in one go:

```
(define (reverse-filter p? xs)
  (define (helper lst acc)
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (helper (cdr lst)
                (let ((a (car lst)))
                  (if (p? a)
                      (cons a acc)
                      acc)))))
  (helper xs '()))

(reverse-filter symbol? '(1 2 3 a b c))
; ==> (c b a)
```